# Listview With Custom Adapter, Checkbox Items And Select All option

Tags: android-studio

I have an application that populate data from sqlite and put in a listview

1 of the holder in listview layout is a checkbox.

I also have 1 checkbox in the forupload activity which named select all, that if all the items in the listview are checked, the select all checkbox will be set as checked. And if I check the select all checkbox, all the items in the listview will be checked

**ForUploadActivity.xml**

```
<CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chckbox_selectall_forUpload"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SELECT ALL"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:drawableEnd="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_forUpload"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

**ListviewLayout.xml**
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/holder_name_forUpload"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/holder_address_forUpload"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

```
**ForUploadActivity**
```

ListView New_forUpload_List;
private Button Upload_Selected_Items, Delete_All;
com.vicjames.irca.ListAdapters.ForUploadListAdapter forUploadListAdapter;
private ArrayList list_forUpload_id = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList list_forUpload_name = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList list_forUpload_address = new ArrayList<>();

```
CheckBox select_All;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_for_upload);

    New_forUpload_List= findViewById(R.id.listview_forUpload);
    select_All = findViewById(R.id.chckbox_selectall_forUpload);
    viewData_forUpload();
    New_forUpload_List.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }
    });
    select_All.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

        }
    });

    
}

public void viewData_forUpload() {
    db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = db.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT ID, (Last_Name || ' ' || First_Name || ' ' || Middle_Name) as Name, (Barangay || ' ' || Town) as Address FROM FOR_UPLOAD", null);
    list_forUpload_id.clear();
    list_forUpload_name.clear();
    list_forUpload_address.clear();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            list_forUpload_id.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID")));
            list_forUpload_name.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")));
            list_forUpload_address.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Address")));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    forUploadListAdapter = new com.vicjames.irca.ListAdapters.ForUploadListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            this.list_forUpload_asc_rec,
            this.list_forUpload_name,
            this.list_forUpload_address);

    New_forUpload_List.setAdapter(forUploadListAdapter);
    cursor.close();
}
```

```
**ForUploadListAdapter**
```

public class ForUploadListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private Context context;
private ArrayList list_upload_id;
private ArrayList list_upload_name;
private ArrayList list_upload_address;

```
public ForUploadListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list_upload_id, ArrayList<String> list_upload_name, ArrayList<String> list_upload_address) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list_upload_id = list_upload_id;
    this.list_upload_name = list_upload_name;
    this.list_upload_address = list_upload_address;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list_upload_id.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ForUploadListAdapter.Holder holder;
    if (view == null)
    {
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") LayoutInflater layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService("layout_inflater");
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_for_upload_list, null, true);
        holder = new ForUploadListAdapter.Holder();
        holder.holder_fordownload_id = view.findViewById(R.id.holder_id_forUpload);
        holder.holder_fordownload_name = view.findViewById(R.id.holder_name_forUpload);
        holder.holder_fordownload_address = view.findViewById(R.id.holder_address_forUpload);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ForUploadListAdapter.Holder)view.getTag();
    }
    holder.holder_fordownload_id.setText(list_upload_id.get(i));
    holder.holder_fordownload_name.setText(list_upload_name.get(i));
    holder.holder_fordownload_address.setText(list_upload_address.get(i));

    if (i % 2 == 1)
    {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#708090"));
    }
    else
    {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00574B"));
    }

    return view;
}

public class Holder
{
    CheckBox holder_fordownload_id;
    TextView holder_fordownload_name, holder_fordownload_address;

    private Holder()
    {

    }
}
```

}

```
I tried [this][1] but I can't make it work..

can anyone give me idea how to implement this function in my project..

Thank you in advance..


  [1]: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-all-checked-items-in-a-listview-in-android
```

Comment: This looks like a general programming question to ask on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com). It does not appear to require game development specific expertise.

Comment: yah..but they deleted that question. Now I can't post or ask anything there.. When I open the site.. it says "You have a history of asking low quality questions."

Comment: You might want to work on that then, before you face a similar restriction here. For example, I notice you didn't even format your code above consistently. This sends a message to other users "your experience of reading my question is not worth my time" so they may very well feel that answering the question is not worth their time in return. Your question should also explain what you tried (not just link to a tutorial), and detail exactly where it went wrong / what specific problem you ran into trying to make it work.